# What is the original domain in Cross domain request?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have a web page from domain1 that is requesting a javascript file from domain2 , and the javascript file is making XMLHttprequest to domain3.
So my question is what is the original domain that can't be crossed or need to be listed on server , for making the last XMLHttprequest to domain3 ?

Comment: The domain from where the request is being sent.

Comment: that means ?? form domain1 or domain2 ??

Comment: The term you want is *origin*, and the origin for a request is the origin where the JavaScript executes in the browser. So in the case described in your question, it’s domain1.